# Can't get monocov to compile (Mac OS x 10.7.4)

Tags: c#, mono

I am desperately searching for a coverage utility within mono. I have written some tests but there are most likely some parts of the code that are not excersized by my tests. I have been searching for a few weeks now for a coverage program that I can use with my dll's that are generated from my ASP.NET MVC project. I came across the monocov module and I have downloaded the source over [here](https://github.com/mono/monocov)! as [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/Code_Coverage)! told me to. I copied Mono.Cecil.dll into the source directory (for monocov) and installed the XCode command line tools. By looking through the makefile i should be good if i type "make install". It seems to compile a few classes but then it starts spitting out errors about Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.

I have exhausted everything that my current knowledge knows to do and I need to take a breather... i'm probably going to write some more tests and let this escape my mind for a bit but I wanted to post it up here and see if there was anybody willing to help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a copy of Cecil 0.6. It is a bit harder to find as the entire Mono project has gone through a lot of changes over the past 2 years, but last I checked (10. Sept 2012) there is a copy available from the authors' personal blog here http://evain.net/blog/articles/2007/10/05/mono-cecil-0-6

You can pick the .tar.gz version for instance. Inside, there are 3 files. Put these into the monocov source directory. Run the configure script. Open the makefile and find the line saying something like "CFLAGS=-O2 -g". Append to it so it reads "CFLAGS=-O2 -g -m32". Then make.

Comment: Hit it on the head! Thank you for helping me step through this. I was close but my lack of C/C++ knowledge and using makefiles was preventing me from creating the executable I wanted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Little difficult to get running with mono... but definitely works